# How to save an input value using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

I am working on a website that contains a field called comments where some particular users can post those comments.
My HTML code:

```html
<form>
  <input ng-model="stack"></input>
  <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
  <p>Your comment:  <span ng-bind="stack"></span></p>
</form>
```

The comments should be saved in to a variable then, posted in my web service which is a json file so I can do my Database calls. I have to use $http.post 
I am using AngularJS and I have written my webservice using java (JAXB).

```js
//Controller:
$scope.save = function() { 
  alert(name); 
} 
//In save I put alert to test because all the functions save I tested hadn't done what I need. 
//server 
$http({ 
  method: 'POST', 
  url: 'url', 
  data: "stack=" 
});
```

Comment: show your controller and service code.

Comment: Controller:
$scope.save = function()
 {
 alert(name);
 }
In save I put alert to test because all the functions save I tested hadn't done what I need.
server 
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'url',
    data: "stack=" 
});

Comment: provide it in the question. Not in the comments

Comment: I edited my question :)

Comment: put the $http inside the save method.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$http.post` does it for you.

This is the html code :

```html
<form ng-submit="save()">
      <input ng-model="stack"></input>
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
      <p>Your comment:<span ng-bind="stack"></span></p>
</form>
```

This is the controller function :

```js
function myController($scope,$http){
        $scope.save=function(){
            
      var data=$scope.stack;  
       /* post to server*/
        $http.post(url, data)
            .then(
           function(response){
          // success callback
                 }, 
           function(response){
           // failure callback
               });
                               
             }
        }
```

Comment: I got this error:
ReferenceError: $http is not defined
    at k.$scope.save
whenever I try to save the input value

Comment: Have you put the $http on the header of your controller  function like : " myController($scope,$http)" ?

Comment: function($scope, AppName) and AppName is my factory's name

Comment: So change it for function($scope, $http, AppName) for the injection.

Comment: @NotBad4U How can I store this as a java object? So I would be able to use this value in my classes

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.save = function (data1) {
            var value = JSON.stringify(data1);
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                url: serviceBasePath + '/api/save',
                data: value,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                }
            }).success(function (data, status) {
                $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                $scope.tableParams.reload();
                $scope.Form.$setPristine();
            }).error(function (data, status) {
                $scope.errors = [];
                $scope.errors.push(data);
            });
        };
```