# How to store input values as java object in single page app?

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

I am trying to store html input value as an java object in Single Page application.

In the home.html I enter some data into the input value. When I form action #/about my address is coming out as null. But if I change it to "/helloDetails", I get a rest page and I get the value that I inputted. But doing that would refresh my page. I want it to route to #/about page and have the controller to retrieve the address (look at controller class below).

**Home.HTML**

```
 <div class="container-4">
  <form action="#/about" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address..." "/>
    <button class="icon"  type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute']);

App.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
     .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
        controller : 'aboutController'
        })
        });

App.controller('aboutController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
    $http.get('/helloDetails/').then(function(response) {
        $scope.greeting = response.data;
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/helloDetails")
public Map<String, Object> data(Address address) throws MalformedURLException {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();         
    model.put("addid", address.getAddress());
    System.out.println(address.getAddress() + "Hello Details @@@@@");

  return model
}
```

**About.html**

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<h1>About Page</h1>

<p>{{ message }}</p>
<p> aa {{greeting.addid}} </p>
```

Here is all my data, what am I doing wrong?

**Attempt**

**Html**

```
<form ng-submit="save()">
<input type="text" name="address"placeholder="Address..." ng-model="stack"/>
<button class="icon"  type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
<p> hello this is : <span ng-bind="stack"></span></p>
```

**Javascript**

```
App.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {

    var data=$scope.stack;
    $http.post('/helloDetails', data)
        .then(function(response){

        });
```

This basically prints out what ever user types into the input box.

Comment: @faffaffaff my controller is java. I could have made a mistake in my controller.

Comment: generally you would send the data to server using $http not through form and `action="#/about"` makes no sense. Store the data in a service and use `$location.path('/about');` to change route after you receive the data response

Comment: @charlietfl I understand, users have to input values. How would I be able to store the values that the users inputted as a service?  Would this be the post I should follow ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541212/how-to-save-an-input-value-using-angularjs

Comment: whatever the user is inputting, is in its respective `ng-model` value. Take it, put it in a `JSON` and send it using `$http` to the Java API.